# how to add textbox values to crystal reports in c#

Tags: c#

firs of all i need say i have seen previous questions and answers. but they want works for me. i know it was my fault. but cant find any solution.
i'm new to crystal reports. i have create a crystal report and try o add values in my form..

this is my code

```
 private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string reportPath = "~\\WindowsFormsApplication10\\fullServiceReport.rpt";

        ReportDocument fullServiceRpt = new ReportDocument();
        fullServiceRpt.Load(reportPath);
        fullServiceRpt.SetParameterValue("@cusName", TextBoxCusName.Text);
    }
```

and it will genaratw exception like this
[image]

Comment: are you passing datasource or connecting to sql directly ?

Comment: no. value is taking from my form

Comment: how you create your crystal report

Comment: by right click on project

Comment: i mean to say when you create your report what you use to get field list by connecting sql or by class object or dataset and cusName is field or label

Comment: oh it's parameter field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64529/discussion-between-saranga-sachinthana-and-pramod-maurya).

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter